# Recommended WPF Project Structure?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, project-planning, project-structure

I'm a stickler for good Visual Studio Solution and Project structures.

I'm about to start a WPF proof of concept piece of work.

Can anyone recommend some WPF Project structures they have used and found worked well?

Here http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/01/58/

They have one recommendation which I like:

```
    Root
    - Pages
    - Controls
    - Resources
    App.xaml
```

Where Pages, Controls and Resources are folders.

Has anyone found certain structures work well / don't work well?

Also I'd rather not get into a 'Model View Presenter' discussion if that's ok with you guys.

Comment: Seriously, why do you need some validation on something like this? You can drag/drop stuff round later if you need to, and the refactoring support in VS (especially 2010) is rather good.

Comment: You don't take time at the beginning to plan things before you start?
If you fail to prepare you prepare to fail. Of course you can change things later but thats not really a good argument for not taking the time at the beginning and planning is it?

Comment: My point is: the example you gave is fine, why do you need people to critique it? By all means plan ahead, but also remember that at the start of a project things will be somewhat fluid and you will change locations and namespaces of things. Categorise things in a way that makes sense to **you** and your team. After a week or two you will find things settling down and you won't be moving stuff as much if at all. Organising a *project* is no big deal - organising a *solution* ahead of time has a bigger ROI for your planning time.

Comment: ahh I understand Slugster. I wasn't really looking for a critique on any one method I was trying to encourage a discussion and swapping of ideas and experiences.

Comment: I actually think this is a good question. Unfortunately nobody has raised the issue here, but I'm finding that a single ViewModel folder becomes large and unwieldy. I was hoping for some ideas on how to group VMs in a sensible way. For example, differentiating between parent and child view models. Or grouping them by functional area.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with alimbada. We have also created different projects for View and View models. It makes things easier to maintain in case of huge projects. Directories we had were -

```
 - ViewsRoot
    + Base
    + Controls 
    + Documentation 
    + Forms(Windows)
    + Reports
    + Resources 
    + Themes 
    + Utilities 
    App.xaml

 - ViewModelsRoot
    + Collection
    + Commands
    + Converters
    + Resources 
    + TemplateSelectors
    + ViewModels
    + Views (Interfaces for views) 
    Constants.cs 
    Utility.cs
```

I also believe in planning the structure in advance, this makes easy for all developers to get used to it and follow the same. Doing this later adds confusion and is painful in case you have to create seprate projects. Thats my view and am open to know of other better approches for this.

Comment: I like this. Where would you put Attached Properties / Behavior in this scheme tho? I break that out into a separate folder I call Behavior.

Comment: I also have a 'core' project of wpf items that tend to be reusable across multiple projects. Things like Constants, Utilities, Controls and Behavior (which also likely have project specific counterparts)

Comment: I have been tempted to change the name of Resources to Assets, only because resource is such a loaded concept, especially if you are dealing with localization. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl - We also have a seprate project for Utilities and reusable classes but that's just not WPF specific. Renaming Resources to Assets is also a good idea, very refreshing.

Comment: assets is a term from Microsofts Blend Expression.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to have the following directories: Converters, Models, Resources, ViewModels and Views.

I've also seen a solution where the View and ViewModels have been split out into separate projects (see [BubbleBurst](http://bubbleburst.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52406#) on CodePlex)

Comment: Thanks for getting the ball rolling alimbada

Answer (score 0):

I fully support the concern expressed in this post. I just can´t work without a solid previously thought-out structure. I am even going a bit further and trying to establish something like a pseudocode workflow which, in theory, could be filled out task by task, hopefully with the help of the IDE.
At the moment I can share with whoever is interested a preliminary workflow that I created with Bing:
[preliminary wfw for creating a TreeView+DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vljh.png)
From this (10 years old!?) post, I can see that there is a lot more to this than what I have come up with, but it is doable.
Of course, the type of applications would first have to be identified. Mine would be of the type WPF-DBFirst-desktop, and the current window would be of the type TreeView-DataGrid, the code could be created from one or several patterns and in different languages. And, after 4 months of working alongside Bing, I can see that AI would be a very powerful help for this. When will Microsoft/Visual Source include the possibility for our code to be reviewed for errors by AI?
Wouldn´t that make life easier? particularly when you are 80 and it is your first app?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. and please do not use answer posts to ask questions or to vent frustration about a technology