# Can Pass View to ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

For my project I need to know which View is using my ViewModel

So i created this ViewModel:

```
public class HistoriqueViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public HistoriqueViewModel(MetroWindow view)
    {
        this.MetroWindow = view;          
        this.ExportCommand = new RelayCommand(Export_Ex);          
    }

    private MetroWindow _metroWindow;
    public MetroWindow MetroWindow
    {
        get { return _metroWindow; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _metroWindow)) return;
            _metroWindow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
   } 
   //.........
 }
```

And in the View constructor:

```
 public partial class ViewHisto : MetroWindow
{
    public ViewHisto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext=new HistoriqueMV(this) ;
    }

 }
```

It Work perfectly for me but I want to know if this Break the MVVM Pattern?

Comment: Sounds bad. Your VM shouldn't contain a reference to any UI element. As a matter of fact your VM should be decoupled enough that it could be put in a Portable Class Library and used in other platforms, such as Android.

Comment: Thank you've given me look beyond

Comment: Iresolve this by addin some ServicesClass like DialogueCoordinator

Comment: Yes, typically VM should not reference View. Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3670669/1977871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this breaks MVVM. A properly constructed view model **shouldn't care about what the view is**.

Nothing in your code really suggests *why* you are passing that reference (other than exposing the view as a public property, which is an even *bigger* no-no) but there are several ways around it:

- Pass the view as an interface and hold/expose that
- Use a mediator to pass whatever messages necessary between the view model/view
- Have the view invoke whatever methods it needs on the view model, and have the view model raise events that the view can listen to.

Any of the above approaches will provide far better decoupling than the one you are going with.

<sub>One other thing, its "View Model", not "Model View"</sub>

Comment: Thank you've helped me to progress.

Comment: Iresolve this by addin some ServicesClass like DialogueCoordinator thanks