# View doesn't find ViewModel in different Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I am starting a new project and oriented my projectstructure on the structure recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423033/recommended-wpf-project-structure/3423811#3423811).

Now I am seeing strange behaviour. When I am setting the datacontext in the View-XAML, it isn't found at runtime (getting a `XamlParseException`). When I set it in the constructor in the codebehind-file, everything is working just fine.

Is this official (documented) behaviour when using different assemblies, or am I doing something wrong?

The code:

*Not Working:*

`MainView.xaml:`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ViewsRoot.Views.MainView"             
         xmlns:baseControls="clr-namespace:BaseControls;assembly=BaseControls"            
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModelsRoot;assembly=ViewModelsRoot">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

`MainView.xaml.cs`

```
public MainView() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // No DataContext set in codebehind-file    
}
```

*Working:*

`MainView.xaml:`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ViewsRoot.Views.MainView"             
         xmlns:baseControls="clr-namespace:BaseControls;assembly=BaseControls"            
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModelsRoot;assembly=ViewModelsRoot">
<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext> -->
```

`MainView.xaml.cs:`

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModelsRoot.ShellViewModel();
}
```

**Update:**

The Exception-Text is:

> {"The file or assembly \" ViewModelsRoot, PublicKeyToken = null \ "or one of its dependencies was not found. The system can not find the file specified."}

And the only inner Exception I can see is a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

**Update 2:**

Thanks for the comments, but I haven't forgotten a namespace. I shortened it here for showing the code, but I double- and triplechecked (again). The DataContexts namespace is also filled in by intellisense. The whole `<viewModels:ShellViewModel />` is written by intelli-sense. So it is found at designtime... ...so any more ideas?

**Update 3:**
The xaml is "correctly" parsed as I am able to bind the DataContext to a class in the same assembly.

Comment: Is there any inner exception?

Comment: You may have forgotten some namespaces in your `UserControl`. Check if this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852912/xamlparseexception-in-view

Comment: Well, I know I faced this exception in the past. Check that all the references used in the assembly of your viewmodel, are also referenced in the one of your View. As the inner exception states, some files are missing. Up to you to find which one!

Comment: Thanks for your help @Guillaume but there are no references missing or otherwise it wouldn't work in the codebehind-file. Also adding all references of the viewmodel-project to the view-project would completely work against the mvvm-pattern and I wouldn't need seperation of them in the first place.

Comment: I'm more thinking of some Framework assemblies, like Microsoft.CSharp or so. Which are used by the XAML engine to render the control. The stuff that needs to transform `<UserControl.DataContext><viewModels:ShellViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>` into `this.DataContext = new ShellViewModel();`

Comment: have you tried adding `using ViewModelsRoot;` into your code-behind file?

Answer (score 3):

I have reproduced this error using a three project solution, with the specified dependencies between them:

- StartupProject → ViewsRoot
- ViewsRoot → ViewModelsRoot
- ViewModelsRoot

"StartupProject" has "exe" output type, while the other two have "dll".

In my case, I solved the problem by adding "ViewModelsRoot" to the References list of "StartupProject". It is not a coding problem, but rather a runtime problem, because "ViewModelsRoot.dll" is not copied to "StartupProject" output folder.

When you specify the DataContext in code-behind, Visual Studio notices the need for that "dll" and adds it to the output after compilation. This doesn't happen when setting the DataContext from XAML. It is tricky because "ViewModelsRoot" code is used from XAML with Reflection. Adding it to References list forces Visual Studio to copy the "dll" in both cases.

You can also copy "ViewModelsRoot.dll" to the output folder directly, but it will not be updated when you change the code.

Comment: This is interesting.  I had the same issue and resolved it with this fix but to me it's a dirty fix.  I don't want to have that reference in my startup project and I do want my projects independent.  I noticed this never happened to me in the past but in the past I always had some coding reference to a ViewModel.  So... A less obvious hack is to just add a private class to your Views project and call it whatever you want and just add a field to a ViewModel in the ViewModel project.  It doesn't even have to be instantiated, just there for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I've often found this error when the project target framework was set to "Client Profile" (this was set by default on VS2010, IIRC), if this is the case, try changing it to 3.5 or 4.0.

Comment: Sorry. No luck - it is .net4-Full Profile.

Comment: Any chance you can upload your project so I can take a look?